# Dealing with a table with too many row in org-mode

Tags: org-table

When a table gets too long, how can you deal with it? Is there any way of collapsing parts of it? Or maybe dividing it in multiple tables and still perform operations (like adding a column) on all of them as one?

Comment: Too long for **what**?